# How to prevent CMake rerun after CMakeLists.txt changed?

Tags: cmake, compilation, mercurial, revision, cmakelists-options

I am working on a project in Mercurial with CMake in Windows Visual Studio 2022.
CMake reruns every time I switch from one revision to another, which changes CMakeLists.txt, and a very time costly build follows.

Could one explain please how CMake decides the time passed to rerun?
Does cmake rerun always mean regenerating all the Makefiles?
How to prevent the mass compilations?

Comment: The build system inherently depends on the CMakeLists.txt files. There is no way to do this and it would be a bad idea to omit the dependency anyway. This is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Most likely your build is doing a bad job of managing dependencies and/or command line flags (as targets depend also on the commands used to build them).

Comment: at least on linux you have `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache` to prevent "the mass compilation" ...